# Program that sums values that contains points and commas

Tags: vb.net

I don't know how to sum values that contains points and commas

For example 10.000,00 + 1.000,00 = 11.000,00

So this would be ten thousand plus one thousand equals eleven thousand.

I have these numbers as strings and I am trying to convert them using `Double.Parse()` but it gave me an error saying it's wrong format.

I am programming in VB.NET

So how can I sum those numbers?

Comment: Clearly your globalization settings are not compatible with the two strings. Use Double.Parse passing the appropriate CultureInfo.

Comment: `Dim culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ro-RO") Dim sum As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(string1, culture) + Decimal.Parse(string2, culture)`. `Decimal.TryParse()` if you need to make sure the values are convertible. The CultureInfo may be just `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` or `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` if already localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, 10.000,00 + 1.000,00 = 11.000,00, replace the Commas with Points, and those Pre-Existing points, with nothing.

Like this --> 10000.00 + 1000.00 = 11000.00

Answer (score 1):

You  can either use a `CultureInfo` that already defines the format you desire (as suggested in the comments), or you can specify the format yourself by cloning and modifying the `CurrentCulture`

```vb
Dim culture As Globalization.CultureInfo = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ","c
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = "."c

'use your custom defined culture when calling parse
Decimal.Parse(yourString, culture.NumberFormat)

'Or if calling TryParse
Decimal.TryParse(yourString, Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, culture.NumberFormat, result)
```